# iphone Native Email Client UI

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have my own custom UI that renders email. but it renders only text mails. Now I am extending it to support HTML formatted mails. I wanted to know how Apple does it in native email client and then replicate the same in my App's UI. In particular, I am interested in knowing what UI component is used by the native email client to display the Mail body. All HTML text is rendered properly in it and also you are allowed to edit it. I am trying to create something similar from scratch for my app. I don't want to use MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: they used a private API or a private framework or something else that is not available for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not publically known what component Apple uses. You can try using a UIWebView.

That said, you pretty much are aiming for rejection if you use anything other than the default MFMailComposeViewController.  The review will want a *good* excuse at best. At worst, they'll just reject your app outright.

If you are looking to allow users to edit the HTML, then use a TextView to edit and the regular message composer to preview.

Comment: Also, I don't think this would provide the edit functionality @Bogus Boy is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Moshe said, your app is likely to be rejected if it doesn't perform functions beyond that of the default Mail application.

Comment: It does perform other functions and is already on the App store. All We wanted was to allow our users to edit HTML Formatted Mails since we had our own Custom UI to render mails. It is an enterprise app and there is a protocol which doesn't allow us to use native mail API's. That's the reason we created our own custom UI